# Error (10818): Can't infer register for at .. because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge

Tags: vhdl

i'm new at vhdl and i have two problems :

- the one in the topic ->Error (10818): Can't infer register for "syn_reset" at RESET_BLOCK.vhd(49) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
- Error (10822): HDL error at RESET_BLOCK.vhd(49): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge

i've searched for any tips but i didn't found any that could match my problems (with the code). I want to send a sequence beetween the falling edge of the clock and it's rising edge. Mayby i just don't gest vhdl right. Here's the code :

...

```
reset_signal_write :process (sclk_reset_in,init) 
begin
  selected :if init = '1' then
     scs_reset <= '0' ;          
     sdata_reset <= '1';  
     syn_reset <= '0' after 30 ns;
     falling_edge_detected :if falling_edge(sclk_reset_in) then 
        sdata_reset <= '0' after 30 ns; 
        sdata_reset <= '1' after 60 ns ;
        sdata_reset <= '0' after 90 ns;
        sdata_reset <='1' after 120 ns;     
        rising_edge_detected :if rising_edge(sclk_reset_in) then
           syn_reset <= '1' after 30 ns;
           scs_reset <= '1' after 60 ns;
        end if rising_edge_detected;
     end if falling_edge_detected ;
```

...

Thanks for Your help!

Comment: Is this code for simulation, or do you expect it to be able to work when synthesized? If it needs to be synthesized, you can't get away with "after X ns" - it won't work. But if this is only for simulation, then that can be ok.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986966/cant-infer-register-for-at-because-it-does-not-hold-its-value-outside-t

Comment: i want to synthesize it, i've seen that post earlier but i didn't see anything helpful.

Comment: To get these delays you're going to have to create a counter that ticks off every 10, 15, or 30 ns and use that in conjunction with an FSM to control sequencing of the outputs. It is generally a bad idea to mix `rising_edge` and `falling_edge` in the same process. It sets you up for timing problems down the road. You may be able to treat `sclk_reset_in` as data registered by the 100MHz, 66MHz, or 33MHz clock needed for the counter and run everything off the rising edge.

Comment: Additionally you only check if there is a rising edge when there is a falling edge. This will never be true.

Comment: [This E.SE question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121121/why-cannot-delays-be-synthesized-in-verilog)'s title says Verilog, but @Blup1980's answer is applicable to any language.